# GDAL - How to get geometry type of a MapInfo TAB file?

Tags: python, gdal, mapinfo, ogr

I am using the OGR MapInfo File driver to read a MapInfo TAB file. However, the function [GetGeomType()](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#GetGeomType) returns 0 which means 'wkbUnknown` even if the features in the TAB are only multi-polygons.

Is it because MapInfo TAB can store many different GeomTypes in the same file?

If I take for granted that only one geometry type would always be in the TAB, how could I retrieve it?

```
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("MapInfo File")
        datasource = driver.Open(os.path.join(dirname,shapefileName))
        layer = datasource.GetLayer(0)
        geometryType = layer.GetGeomType()

        >>>geometryType
        >>>0
```

Comment: What does `layer.GetLayerDefn()` return? Also [this discussion](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2002-November/000023.html) on the osgeo mailing list might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the OGR MapInfo File driver, GetGeomType() will return wkbPoint, wkbLineString or wkbUnknown for MapInfo TAB file. The later being for polygons/multipolygons, or mix or geometry types.

Source is ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mitab/mitab_tabfile.cpp :

```
    if( numPoints > 0 && numLines == 0 && numRegions == 0 )
        m_poDefn->SetGeomType( wkbPoint );
    else if( numPoints == 0 && numLines > 0 && numRegions == 0 )
        m_poDefn->SetGeomType( wkbLineString );
    else
        /* we leave it unknown indicating a mixture */;
```

I imagine (I haven't coded that driver) that the reason is that regions can be
either a mix of Polygon and MultiPolygon, hence it is not possible to expose a
single geometry type.
Well, in the shapefile driver, the same situation occurs and we expose
wkbPolygon, but can indeed cause some issues when converting to other formats.
A potential solution would be to declare MultiPolygon as geometry type and
indeed return single Polygon in a MultiPolygon.